# Service / process responsible for processor scaling in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cpu, resource-monitor

Frequently after wake-up from sleep, Windows 7 get stuck on low processor frequency (e. g 29 % - displayed in Resource Monitor) while processor utilization is near 100 %. The system is thus not very responsive.

Is there any service / process I can restart to make processor scaling work again? Or is computer restart inevitable?

Hardware is Dell Latitude E7440 with i5 processor.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no built in Windows tool for adjusting the dynamic processor scaling in Windows.  However, there are 3rd party tools you can try like [ParkControl](https://bitsum.com/parkcontrol/).

Comment: I do not want to adjust it, I want just to restore normal operation without restarting OS.